# How to redirect HTTPS non-www to HTTPS www using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When I visit my site at https://example.com, my browser responds with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Note that the following all work:

- https://www.example.com
- http://example.com redirects to https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com

How can I redirect https://example.com requests to https://www.example.com using .htaccess?

I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
// .htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rules is using `AND` operation between 2 conditions but you `OR`.

You can use this rule for enforcing both `www` and `https`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

**EDIT:** As per comments below just for `https://example.com to https://www.example.com` redirect you can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I tried this but I think it's conflicting with existing rules in httpd.conf. Is there a way of redirecting to www only if the request is `https://example.com`?

Comment: What if original URL is `http://www.example.com`, don't you need to be `https://www.example.com`. btw you can use this rule in httpd.conf also, just remember to restart Apache and clear browser cache every time (or test using curl command line)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @anubhava. `http://www.example.com` already redirects to `https://www.example.com`. It's just the `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` that needs handling.

Comment: Yes I know other redirect is working for you but my rule is supposed to replace all the `www` and `http->https` rule+code you already have. Reason is that multiple 301 redirects will hurt your SEO and will slow down your clients.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

The rule you have should work as it is.

From `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, I would guess Apache isn't listening on the https (443) port.

But since everything else works, even the redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, there might be some other network related problem, like a firewall configuration allowing https through www.example.com, but blocking via example.com. You should check with your server provider.

Comment: Thanks that's useful to know. I'll check!

Answer (score 0):

non-www to www with https

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Its not able to redirect "https://" to "https:// www" Please revise it.